# How to install Chrome extensions on Opera?

Tags: macos, google-chrome-extensions, opera

When I go to the chrome extension store, I cannot install ANY of its extensions. The *add to google chrome* button is greyed out, I don't see an *add to opera* button, and there is a warning saying "*Installation currently unavailable*".

https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/discordmate-discord-chat/ofjlibelpafmdhigfgggickpejfomamk

Now using Chrome browser I see the same thing on the page, and the browser says that I must have Mac OS 10.13 or later !!! Did they just ban older OS to install extensions ??

I'm using Opera Version :89.0.4447.91 (x86_64)
Mac OS 10.12
Mac Intel

[image: chrome extension page]

Comment: "To install extensions from the Google Chrome Store into Opera, you must first download and install the Install Chrome Extensions addon from the Opera Addons Store." have you done this?

Comment: [Install Chrome extensions in Opera | Extensions for writers - Blog | Opera Tips & Tricks](https://blogs.opera.com/tips-and-tricks/2021/10/using-addons-from-chrome-in-opera/)

Comment: @DavidPostill https://forums.opera.com/topic/58248/solved-install-chrome-extensions-is-missing

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I'm afraid you'll find half the interweb no longer works properly if your macOS is that far out of date.
It's getting to be a struggle even on Mojave.

You're so far out of support that I wouldn't expect any new app/product to work on Sierra. Even your Opera is almost 20 versions out of date. The latest version requires Catalina 10.15 minimum spec - some apps now require Big Sur 11.0 minimum.

On Mojave I found older Opera versions at https://get.opera.com/ftp/pub/opera/desktop/ & guessed at which I might be able to run, v100 which worked. It then auto-updated to v102 but won't go any further.
That version will allow me to *try* to install your linked extension, but the install itself fails. I'd have to conclude that you're not going to get it to work on Sierra either.

Answer (score 0):

This user script modifies the chrome webstore page and lets any browser install the extensions.

https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/479807-chrome-new-webstore-make-available-for-all-web-browsers-which-support-it